# Getting the wrong sorted distance on the basis of lat and long

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am getting very strange issues in my app,there is a section where i am collecting the data from the server, in response i am getting the lat and long for all the near by restaurants,by using these lat and long i am getting the distances of each from the current user location,and i have applied the sorting like closet to further from the current user location on the collected data,everthing works fine at my end but whenever client test this at his end then the sorting doesn't work.I have attached  the code for this here.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    myDelegate= (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSLog(@"Lat %f", [[myDelegate.myLocation objectForKey:@"LATITUDE"]floatValue]);
    NSLog(@"Long %f",[[myDelegate.myLocation objectForKey:@"LONGITUDE"]floatValue]);

    self.coordArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.


    timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(10.0) target:self selector:@selector(upateLocation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    float dist;

    for (int i=0; i<[myDelegate.placeArray count]; i++) {

        dist=(6371 * acos(cos(RADIANS_TO_DEGREES([[myDelegate.myLocation objectForKey:@"LATITUDE"]floatValue]) ) *
                                     cos(RADIANS_TO_DEGREES([[[myDelegate.placeArray objectAtIndex:i] latitude] floatValue] ) ) * cos( RADIANS_TO_DEGREES([[[myDelegate.placeArray objectAtIndex:i] longitude] floatValue] ) - RADIANS_TO_DEGREES([[myDelegate.myLocation objectForKey:@"LONGITUDE"]floatValue]) ) + sin( RADIANS_TO_DEGREES([[myDelegate.myLocation objectForKey:@"LATITUDE"]floatValue])) * sin( RADIANS_TO_DEGREES([[[myDelegate.placeArray objectAtIndex:i] latitude] floatValue] ) ) ) );

        //int distVal=(int)dist;
        distStr= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",dist];
        NSLog(@"new---%@",distStr);
        [self.coordArray addObject:distStr];
    }
    NSMutableDictionary *tmpDict;

    for (int i=0; i<[myDelegate.placeArray count]; i++) {

        tmpDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:[[myDelegate.placeArray objectAtIndex:i] ids],@"contentId",[[myDelegate.placeArray objectAtIndex:i] restaurantname],@"contentTitle",//contentAdd
                   [[myDelegate.placeArray objectAtIndex:i] res_type],@"contentType",
                   [[myDelegate.placeArray objectAtIndex:i] user_image],@"contentImg",[[myDelegate.placeArray objectAtIndex:i] address],@"contentAdd",[[myDelegate.placeArray objectAtIndex:i] phone],@"contentPhone",
                   [self.coordArray objectAtIndex:i],@"contentDist",nil];

        [self.dataArray addObject:tmpDict];
        [tmpDict release];
        tmpDict = nil;


        //  NSLog(@"self.dataArray---%f",[[[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"contentDist"] floatValue]);
    }

    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [tempArray removeAllObjects];
    [tempArray addObjectsFromArray: self.dataArray];

    NSString *key = @"contentDist";
    NSSortDescriptor *brandDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:key ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:brandDescriptor,nil];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [tempArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [brandDescriptor release];
    [tempArray removeAllObjects];
    tempArray = (NSMutableArray*)sortedArray;
    [self.dataArray removeAllObjects];
    [self.dataArray addObjectsFromArray:tempArray];

    /*haversine=[[Haversine alloc] init];
     [haversine initWithLat1:28.618095 lon1:77.390228 lat2:28.635860 lon2:77.506226];
     [haversine toKilometers];
     NSLog(@"haversine--- %f",[haversine toKilometers]);*/
//    [self performSelector:@selector(upateLocation) withObject:nil afterDelay:10.0];


    }

}
```

Here is the explanation of the above code.
1-Have an Array (place Array) which having all lat and long corresponding to each restaurants.
2-From this array,by using Harvest method i am getting the distances in km and then adding these into another array named (coordArray).
3-Then Creating a final array i.e (dataArray on which i have applied the sorting

This works fine at my end but doesn't work once i tested on iPhone 5.
Can anyone suggest me what is wrong with this code which i am not geting.

Please help me out from this and thanks to all for giving your precious time .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really an answer but I believe you can reformat your code to remove lots of unnecessary looping. Just made the code similar to yours you can store the distance as NSNumber. You can also use fast enumeration to remove lots of verbosity.

```
self.dataArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i=0; i<[myDelegate.placeArray count]; i++) {

    float dist=(6371 * acos(cos(RADIANS_TO_DEGREES([[myDelegate.myLocation objectForKey:@"LATITUDE"]floatValue]) ) *
                      cos(RADIANS_TO_DEGREES([[[[myDelegate.placeArray objectAtIndex:i] latitude] floatValue] ) ) * cos( RADIANS_TO_DEGREES([[[myDelegate.placeArray objectAtIndex:i] longitude] floatValue] ) - RADIANS_TO_DEGREES([[myDelegate.myLocation objectForKey:@"LONGITUDE"]floatValue]) ) + sin( RADIANS_TO_DEGREES([[myDelegate.myLocation objectForKey:@"LATITUDE"]floatValue])) * sin( RADIANS_TO_DEGREES([[[myDelegate.placeArray objectAtIndex:i] latitude] floatValue] ) ) ) );

    //int distVal=(int)dist;
    NSString *distStr= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",dist];

    NSDictionary *tmpDict = @{@"contentId":[[myDelegate.placeArray objectAtIndex:i] ids],
                              @"contentTitle":[[myDelegate.placeArray objectAtIndex:i] restaurantname],
                              @"contentType":[[myDelegate.placeArray objectAtIndex:i] res_type],
                              @"contentImg":[[myDelegate.placeArray objectAtIndex:i] user_image],
                              @"contentAdd":[[myDelegate.placeArray objectAtIndex:i] address],
                              @"contentPhone":[[myDelegate.placeArray objectAtIndex:i] phone],
                              @"contentDist":distStr};

    [self.dataArray:tmpDict];
}

NSSortDescriptor *brandDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"contentDist"
                                                                  ascending:YES];

[self.dataArray sortUsingDescriptors:@[brandDescriptor]];
```

Comment: Thanks Anup, it's working at our end as it was working ealriaer but at the client end it's not working.It sort some values correctly but on some values it's doesn't work.Can you please suggest.

Comment: @FlexsinFlex Since sorting is based on the distance. Double check it's values. My suggestion was to remove many verbose steps for more readability and easiness to debug. Since you have a model object for storing, you can move the creation of dictionary to that class. And then you only need to add distance to create tmpDict(formed from model).

Answer (score 2):

If you store the distances as *strings*:

```
distStr= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",dist];
NSLog(@"new---%@",distStr);
[self.coordArray addObject:distStr];
```

then they will be sorted as strings and not as numbers, for example `11.00 < 2.00`.

You should store the distances as `NSNumber` objects instead:

```
[self.coordArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:dist]];
```

(Note that CLLocation has a [`distanceFromLocation:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/distanceFromLocation%3a)
method that you could use instead of your own computation.)